# Correlation and Covariance of random variable sin and cos

Tags: probability, self-study

How do I get the  $\rho(Y_1 ,Y_2)$
for $K =$ a random variable with values $0, \frac{\pi}2$, $\pi$ with probability $\frac13$ each. $Y_1 = \sin(K) $, $Y_2 = \cos(K) $ ?

I understand I've to get the joint probability to get the covariance and also the standard deviation but I'm stuck in this for quite some time

Comment: What do you want to do with sine and cosine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me help you with the joint distribution.

We have $Pr(K=0) = \frac13$,  $Pr(K=\frac{\pi}2)=\frac13$, and $Pr(K=\pi)=\frac13$.

If $K=0$, $Y_1=\sin(K)=0, Y_2=\cos(K)=1$.

If $K=\frac{\pi}2$, $Y_1=\sin(K)=1, Y_2=\cos(K)=0$.

If $K=\pi$, $Y_1 = \sin(K)=0, Y_2=\cos(K) = -1.$

Hence, the joint distribution can be written as

$Pr((Y_1, Y_2)=(0,1)) = Pr((Y_1, Y_2)=(1, 0))= Pr((Y_1, Y_2)=(0,-1))=\frac13$.

Try to compute $E[Y_1Y_2], E[Y_1^2], E[Y_2^2], E[Y_1], E[Y_2]$ using the information above and the formula

$$\rho(Y_1, Y_2) = \frac{cov(Y_1, Y_2)}{\sqrt{var(Y_1) var(Y_2)}}$$ to solve your problem.